# How can I pass a positional argument to an optional argument in python functions?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I am writing a gradient descent function for linear regression and want to include a default initial guess of parameters as a numpy zero array whose length is determined by the shape of an input 2D array. I tried writing the following

```
def gradient_descent(X,w0=np.zeros(X.shape[1])):
```

which does not work, raising an error that X is not defined in the optional argument. Is it possible to pass a positional argument to the optional argument in a python function?

Comment: No, you can't. Default value expressions are evaluated *before* the function is defined, so that the resulting value can be stored with the function itself. It's not just an expression that *will* be evaluated once the function is called without an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to contain the logic into the function itself:

```
def gradient_descent(X, w0=None):
    if w0 == None:
        w0 = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
    #Then continue coding here
```

Does that make sense? As a whole, you want to specify the parameters when defining the function, but not include logic. As a concept, the logic should primarily be included into the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
def gradient_descent(X, w0=None):
  if not w0:
    w0 = np.zeros(X.shape[1])
  ...
```